# Power BI - DAX calculate users sessions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new in Power Bi.

Screen below shows member's time spend in the system
I was trying with

```
CALCULATE(SUM('Query1'[Logout Time]) - SUM('Query1'[Login Time])
```

but it seems to doesn't work with hours.
Could you provide any efficient way to do that?

Thanks in advance.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3caLt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
User Sessions = 
SUMX(
    'Table',
    DATEDIFF('Query1'[Login Time], 'Query1'[Logout Time], SECOND)
)
```